# How to change default file extension Eclipse uses for source code files?

Tags: eclipse

How can I change the file extension that Eclipse uses when it creates source code files, say, from `*.cpp` to `*.cc`?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this on the C/C++ version of Eclipse. But I just did it on the Java version and feel the steps will be very similar for you. Here's how I did it.

1. Go to `Window > Preferences > General > Content Types`
2. Find the entry for `*.cpp` and select that
3. Click on the `Add` button under `File Associations`
4. Add the new file extension, `*.cc`
5. Click `OK` and you should be good to go

### Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay, I found it, but *.cc is already there, but by default *.cpp extension is used. Also, order doesn't seem to matter, as *.cpp is about in the middle of the list.